# Is the ascending union of contractible spaces contractible

Tags: general-topology

Let $\{Y_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a collection of subspaces of $X$ such that each $Y_i$ is contractible and $Y_{i} \subseteq Y_{i+1}$. Is $\bigcup_{i\in \mathbb{N}}Y_i \subseteq X$ also contractible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. Consider the half-open arcs
$$Y_n=\{e^{i\theta}\mid \theta\in[0,2\pi-\tfrac{1}{n})\}$$
on the circle $X$.